# Can't pass a function as a value to setAttribute

Tags: javascript, svg

I have some working SVG code that handles mouse events by setting attributes on a shape:

```
function plot() {
  ...
  shape.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseover", "popup_on (evt,"+sindex+","+month+")");
  shape.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout",  "popup_off(evt,"+sindex+")");
}
```

However, I need to change this code, because `popup_on` and `popup_off` are no longer static functions, and need lots of context depending on where they're called from. I'm handling this by defining a closure, and passing a function name as the attribute value:

```
function plot(popup_on, popup_off) {
  ...
  shape.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseover", popup_on  + "(evt,"+sindex+","+month+")");
  shape.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout",  popup_off + "(evt,"+sindex+")");
}
```

However, this doesn't work - the popup code is never fired. If I check the 'shape' attributes in Firebug or Dragonfly they seem to be correct. 'shape' has 'onmouseover' and 'onmouseout' attributes, and the value of the attribute is the complete source text of the `popup_on` and `popup_off` functions:

```
onmouseover=function popup_on(evt, sindex, month) {
  ...
}
```

but the functions aren't actually run.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

### UPDATE

Thanks for all the feedback. Marc's answer doesn't work; 'function' is flagged as a syntax error. 'popup_on' and 'popup_off' aren't strings - they're actually functions in the closure. Both Sime's and Erik's answers did work, though, but with one problem.

If I change the code to this:

```
shape.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {popup_on (evt, sindex, month);}, false);
```

then firebug complains that 'evt' is undefined when it tries to execute `popup_on` (when the mouse hits). If I change `evt` to either `window.evt` or `evt || window.evt`, then I don't get this error, but I still don't have access to the event in the popup handler:

```
   // popup handler in closure
   o["popup_on"] = function(evt, sindex, month) {
      // both evt and window.evt are undefined on entry
      evt = evt || window.evt;
      // so evt is still undefined, but...
      ...
      // I need to do this
      var upright = (evt.clientY >= cy);
```

Any idea why? Thanks.

### UPDATE2

Ok - fixed. The answer is:

```
shape.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {popup_on (evt, sindex, month);}, false);
shape.addEventListener("mouseout",  function(evt) {popup_off(evt, sindex);}, false);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want to add those as attributes, and not as properties like `shape.onmouseover = ...`?

Comment: Passing strings instead of functions to callbacks is eval, therefore it is evil.

Comment: @Šime Vidas— +1, also isn't it pointless to use *setAttributeNS* if no namespace is provided?

Comment: @RobG: It's necessary, if not for being consistent, there are supposedly environments where `setAttributeNS(null...` !== `setAttribute(`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `shape.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {...}, false)`  instead? See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) for some examples.

If you want the event object to be named 'evt' in your function you can name it (you can give it any name you want), like this: `shape.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {...}, false)`

Otherwise the event variable is by default named 'event' inside the listener function, not 'evt'. This is a source of some confusion.

Comment: thanks Erik - I didn't notice your edit until after I did my second update above.

Answer (score 1):

```
popup_on  + "(evt,"+sindex+","+month+")"
```

is see as "the function popup_on plus the string '(evt,' plus the value of sindex plus ..."

It's not interpreted as building a function call.

If you need to dynamically build its parameters, you should do something more like

```
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout",  function() {
    popup_off(evt,sindex);
});
```

Comment: But the name of the function is a string. The token `popup_on` is not the name of the function, but the name of the argument which contains the name of the function as a string...

Comment: Gah. variable functions... Pretty must as bad as variable variables. BAD design, in other words.